# My div won't center HTML CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

My Code

```css
.nav_bar {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 800px;
 height: 23px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #0090bc;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
 border: 2px solid #004D6F;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), inset -2px -2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), inset -2px -2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 10px;
 font-family: arial;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<center>
 <div class="nav_bar">
  <center><font size="5"><span class="shadow"><b>Text</b></span></font></center>
 </div>
</center>
```

The '.nav_bar' div won't centre for some reason! Here is the output! I've added the centre tag to see if it would centre but it wont't can someone please help me

Output:
[image]

Comment: You have position:absolute.  That means you are positioning it explicitly.  It won't ever center itself with that set.

Comment: Also `center` and `font` are deprecated elements and should no longer be used.

Comment: @Lance You actually can center with position absolute... but is a bad practice :). ex. position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -400px; width: 800px;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove

```
position:absolute;
top: 0;
```

Add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/efhu4h4h/

Note that I changed the width to 100px so it would fit in the window.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the `position: absolute` You can add these styles to `.nav_bar` to center it:

```css
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add align:center in your css class.

```
align:center ;
```

It will work for you